# What is hydration in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, next.js, hydration

Currently, I am learning about react and got to know about the term hydration I am not sure How it works, can anyone help please. thanks in advance.

I created react-app and it sometimes gives hydration error to solve this error I am not pretty sure how hydration works so I want clarity on how hydration works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you visit a website that uses ReactJS, the server sends you an HTML file that's been generated by the server. This is called the initial **HTML markup**.

This **markup** contains some elements that will be replaced by React components once the **JavaScript** code runs in the browser. This is where hydration comes in.

To summarize **Hydration** is the process of attaching the existing React components to the existing HTML markup generated by the server. This means that the user can see some of the content of the website faster, even before the JavaScript loads.

Finally by ensuring proper **Hydration**, the website can achieve faster loading times, which ultimately enhances the user experience.